# My Javascript/Html traffic Light sequence needs a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make sure when the button is clicked the images change but when I test the code the images change but they stop after one cycle. Please give some possible solutions on how to add a loop or make the code repeat ,thanks.

```js
var red = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
    redorange = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP9aAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
    green = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAD/AAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
    orange = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP+qAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=";

var lights = [red, redorange, green, orange];
var lightCounter = 0;

function pictureChange(){
  lightCounter += 1;
  document.getElementById('traffic').src = lights[lightCounter];
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1><b> Traffic Lights </b></h1>

<center>
  <button onclick="pictureChange()">Change Lights</button>
</center>

<br><br>

<img width="230" height="400" id="traffic" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=">
```

Comment: add the javascript code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) to loop your array:

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand.

So, given that your array is:

```
var lights = ["red", "orangered", "green", "orange"]
```

If you do:

```
lights[lightCounter % 4]
```

For an increasing `lightCounter`, you'll have the indices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...

```js
var red = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
    redorange = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP9aAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
    green = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAD/AAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
    orange = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP+qAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=";

var lights = [red, redorange, green, orange];
var lightCounter = 0;

function pictureChange(){
  lightCounter += 1;
  document.getElementById('traffic').src = lights[lightCounter % 4];
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1><b> Traffic Lights </b></h1>

<center>
  <button onclick="pictureChange()">Change Lights</button>
</center>

<br><br>

<img width="230" height="400" id="traffic" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=">
```

Answer (score 1):

After `document.getElementById('traffic').src=lights[lightCounter];`, you need to have `if (lightCounter==3) lightCounter=0;` because you only have 4 elements in the array while your loop is going beyond 4.

Comment: Now, when it repeats on the third cycle it skips red light I am not sure how to change that? Thank you for the help you have given.

Comment: This should be your code:

`function pictureChange(){
        document.getElementById('traffic').src=lights[lightCounter];
        lightCounter+=1;
        (lightCounter==3) lightCounter=0;
    }`